# Javascript in the loop in Wordpress not working (nothing pointed in the console)

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, accordion, elementor

I'v been looking for a solution but nothing came up. I'm trying to apply a [javascript code](https://codepen.io/MidkiffAries/pen/ZEbzNpM) where each post is an accordion. I'm using a elementor widget as a shortcode to render it (maybe it is helpful to know this).You can see it in action at https://www.grafflove.com/

The code for one of the posts is as follows:

```js
(function(){
    var accgraffititv110hest = document.getElementsByClassName("accordiongraffititv110hest"), l = accgraffititv110hest.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        accgraffititv110hest[i].firstChild.nextSibling.onclick = function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var panel = this.nextSibling.nextSibling;
            if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            } 
        }
    }
}());
```

```css
/* Accordion element */

.accordiongraffititv110hest > div {
    display: inline-block;
    color: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1em;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0.55em;
}

.accordiongraffititv110hest > div::before {
    vertical-align: super;
    content: "+";
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    will-change: transform;
        cursor: pointer;
}

.accordiongraffititv110hest > div.active::before {
    vertical-align: super;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.accordiongraffititv110hest > section {
    padding: 0 1em;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    will-change: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordiongraffititv110hest" role="tablist">
    <div role="tab"><div style="display:inline-block; width:90%;">Graffiti TV #110: Hest</div></div>
    <section role="tabpanel">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

In each post css class names and variables change to fit the slug of the post... and everything seems to be correct but for some reason the javascript is blocked on  the browser at the time of showing it.

Any clue will be welcome.

Comment: Are you sure that `div class="accordiongraffititv110hest"` exists when that javascript executes?  You could console.log(accgraffititv110hest.length) and make sure it's not zero.

Comment: The usual suspect is DOM not being loaded when the function executes… (probably would throw `cannot read property 'length' of null` – check the console)

Comment: You are alright. I was loading the elements after the script. NOw I have put the script after the elements and works fine. Thanks a lot and sorry for the silly question...

Answer (score 0):

Yes commentators were right and you execute the initialization script before the elements are there. Either you place the script at the footer, or change it to this code:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var accgraffititv110hest = document.getElementsByClassName("accordiongraffititv110hest"),
    l = accgraffititv110hest.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    accgraffititv110hest[i].firstChild.nextSibling.onclick = function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var panel = this.nextSibling.nextSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    }
  }
}());
```

```css
/* Accordion element */

.accordiongraffititv110hest>div {
  display: inline-block;
  color: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1em;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.55em;
}

.accordiongraffititv110hest>div::before {
  vertical-align: super;
  content: "+";
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  will-change: transform;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordiongraffititv110hest>div.active::before {
  vertical-align: super;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.accordiongraffititv110hest>section {
  padding: 0 1em;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  will-change: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordiongraffititv110hest" role="tablist">
  <div role="tab">
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:90%;">Graffiti TV #110: Hest</div>
  </div>
  <section role="tabpanel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </section>
</div>

<div class="accordiongraffititv110hest" role="tablist">
  <div role="tab">
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:90%;">Graffiti TV #110: Hest</div>
  </div>
  <section role="tabpanel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </section>
</div>

<div class="accordiongraffititv110hest" role="tablist">
  <div role="tab">
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:90%;">Graffiti TV #110: Hest</div>
  </div>
  <section role="tabpanel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes you are all right... very silly for my part.... I have put the javscript code after the elements have loaded and now it is working perfect. Thanks a lot and sorry, becuase this was a very stupid question.